# Getting last three "paths" of directory structure in Talend

Tags: talend

I have following directory path:

```
"C:\Users\me\Documents\TOS_DI-Win32-20150508_1414-V5.6.2\configs\site\schemas\me\tablespace"
```

How may I get:
`"schemas\me\tablespace"` part out of the directory even tough directory structure may change: (For example: `C:\dd\\configs\site\schemas\me\tablespace`)

Thanks in advance smile

Comment: Is this path stored in a variable ? please give more details about your Talend job.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a context variable like this : 
Path = "C:\dd\configs\site\schemas\me\tablespace"

and in your tfile component use :
context.Path + "\schemas\me\tablespace"  in file name.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. This is the approach I used:

```
context.filename_scripts = ((String)globalMap.get("tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEDIRECTORY"));
context.filename_scripts = context.filename_scripts.substring((StringHandling.INDEX(context.filename_scripts, "\\schemas\\me\\")), StringHandling.LEN(context.filename_scripts));
```

This seems to be working as intended. Should have read a few things about StringHandling in Talend :)